# How to synchronize multithreaded OpenGL buffer access?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, gpu, undefined-behavior, vbo

I have vertex buffers holding meshes of terrain chunks. Whenever the player edits terrain, the mesh of the corresponding chunk must be regenerated and uploaded to the vertex buffer. Since regenerating the mesh takes some time, I do it in an asynchronous worker thread.

The issue is that the main threads draws the buffer in the same moment the worker thread uploads new data. That means, after the player editing the terrain, a corrupted chunk gets rendered for one frame. It just flares up once and after that, the correct buffers gets drawn.

This kind of made sense to me, we shouldn't write and read the same data at the same time of course. So instead of updating the old buffer, I created a new one, filled it and swapped them. The swapping was just changing the buffer id stored within the terrain chunk struct, so that should be atomic. Hoever, that didn't help.

Due to the fact that OpenGL commands are sent to a queue on GPU, they don't have to be executed when the application on the CPU continues. So I may have swapped the buffers before the new one was actually ready.

I also tried an alternative to switching the buffers, using a mutex for buffer access. The main thread locks the mutex while drawing and the worker thread locks it while uploading new buffer data. However, this didn't help either and it may be because of OpenGL's asynchronous nature, too. The main thread didn't actually draw, but just send draw commands to the GPU. On the other hand, when there really is only one command queue, uploading buffers and drawing them could never occur at the same time, does it?

How can I synchronize the vertex buffer access from my two threads to prevent that an undefined buffer gets drawn for one frame?

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly, I have to say... it's not supposed to work that way. Buffer updates carry implicit synchronization with them, each call to something like `glBufferSubData (...)` is effectively atomic. You don't have to worry about partial writes showing up in the other thread if the implementation is complying properly. That said, there is a crazy amount of overhead for trying to do it this way in the first place - have you considered a circular buffer that your worker threads write into (e.g. back buffer) while the rendering thread reads from another (e.g. front)?

Comment: What part of the API are you using to update these buffers, by the way? Are you mapping and unmapping the buffer, or using `glBufferSubData (...)`?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: hmm. I just assumed daijar is using multiple contexts, otherwise the question would not really make sense.

Comment: Let me clarify the questions that came up. Yes, I am using two contexts, one for each of the two threads. When I said *buffer* in the question, I always referred to vertex buffer, not draw buffer. Only the main thread is drawing. The worker threads uses `glBufferData` to change the data.

Comment: @derhass: That is a good point, I was focusing on the second-to-last paragraph. That for some reason implied to me that he was passing the same context handle between threads to create a mutex of sorts.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I was just using the mutex to synchronize OpenGL calls between the threads, but that isn't needed as I learned now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @danijar: `glBufferData (...)` does not change data, that allocates an entirely new data store and fills it with data. What you are doing by calling that is known as buffer orphaning. Any **pending** command in the pipeline that was using the old data store will be unaffected by this.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Okay, I need that new data store because the mesh size varies with the terrain updates. However, I don't understand why I see "undefined" meshes flickering up then. Is it because the main thread uses the new ids which is already associated with the new buffer which isn't uploaded yet?

Comment: It is not so much that (no new ID is actually created, it is just that the memory referenced by the buffer object points to something different after you call `glBufferData (...)`), as it is the possibility that the commands in the other context have not finished yet. If you have a draw command queued up **before** you called `glBufferData (...)`, it will be unaffected (the old memory remains untouched). But any draw command that the main thread queues **after** `glBufferData (...)` is called and executes before it completes, will have unpredictable results (the new memory will be incomplete).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Can it complete before the memory is complete, with the GPU using a command queue? Ahh, I think I got it, there is one queue for each context, is it? Or buffer creation might not be part of that queue...

Comment: When two separate contexts are involved, yes. They have independent command queues, state machines, etc. Really all that context sharing does is allow you to *reference* the same object across multiple contexts. You do not benefit from the same synchronization guarantees that you would if every command were issued from a single context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must make sure that the buffer update is actually completed before you can use that buffer in your draw thread. The easieast solution would be to call `glFinish` in your update thread after you issued all the update GL commands, and only notify the the draw thread after that returned.

To have a more fine grained control over the synchronization, I would advice you to have a look at *fence sync* objects (as described in the [GL_ARB_sync](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sync.txt) extension). You can issue a fence sync after you issued your update commands and actually store the sync object handle with your buffer handle so that the draw thread can check if the update actually completed (or wait for it). Note that sync objects are kind of special since they are the only objects *not* tied to the GL context, so that they can be used in multi-context setups.

Comment: That sounds interesting. By *update thread* you mean the worker thread updating the vertex buffers, do you?

Comment: @danijar: yes, exactly.

Comment: Good. My goal is to use the old buffer until the new one is uploaded to the GPU, to I can't let the renderer wait for that idly. How would you approach this?

Comment: @danijar: Use a circular buffer, you will always have a `front` buffer that is complete to display while the background thread works on a `back` buffer. After the background thread finishes, you can swap the front and back. It may take an extra frame for an update to appear, but at least you will not have the issue of partial updates appearing anymore.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Can I just use `glFinish()` on the worker thread after  creating and loading the new buffer on the worker thread before swapping the ids? When each context has its own pipeline, this shouldn't create a empty bubble in the main thread's pipeline.

Comment: @danijar: you can use the ARB_sync approach I outlined in my answer. Your worker thread queues up the updated buffers, and the draw thread checks if the head of the queue actually finished the update. If so, it can use it. If not, it can go on rendering with the old buffer, and will check again next frame.

Comment: I would make the worker thread the check and swap ids then. However, I think `glFinish()` might be even more straight forward. Does this command also blocks the other context?

Comment: @danijar: no, the other context shouldn't be affected. If you can afford stalling your worker thread, the `glFinish()` approach is the most simple solution.

Comment: I'll try to get the simple approach working first, and if needed optimize then. Thanks a lot.